# Loop through json response in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I am trying to get a json response, save it to an array and loop through it to look for matches. However, I am having some difficulties.

I get the json response, and push it to an array with:

```js
var array = Object.entries(response);
```

After that I have let's say this array:

```
var array = [
    [
        "default_route",
        { 
            "subnet": "0.0.0.0/0", 
            "name": "Default" 
        }
    ],
    [
        "vpn_subnet",
        "192.168.10.0/24"
    ]
];
```

It still has some objects inside. Now when I try to loop through it I get no output. It's like the loop doesn't even start. Console doesn't print anything. Example of loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log('loop');
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i]; j++) {
        console.log('loop 2');
    }
};
```

Do I have to convert objects to array values first? The json response I get is a lot more detailed and has a lot more objects in it, compared to snippet above. Ultimately I want to loop through the json response and find a match. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: if you don't see `loop` in the console then your array is empty at the time of running the loop. Your array may be being populated asynchronously, so when you run your loop, your array isn't populated yet. Can you show how you get your array and where you run your loop in relation to that?

Comment: Try with `j < array[i].length` in your second loop.

Comment: @Camilo That works! Additional question, is there a way to convert object to array once the loop gets to that part? Like the part with "subnet" and "name".

Comment: That would be a separated question @PujdoP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on your 2nd loop won't work because `array[i]` returns another array instead of a number. Try appending `.length` to it, something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log('loop');
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        console.log('loop 2');
    }
};
```